# A wordpress plugin calendar to be submitted with a form

Tags: wordpress, forms, plugins, calendar, widget

I need a wordpress calendar widget plugin that I can include with a form that gets submitted via POST.  The user clicks a date in the calendar widget and when form gets submitted the selected calendar date gets submitted as well.

Any calendar widget plugins meant for this?

Comment: saw this?  https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7-datepicker/

Comment: but that depends on another form plugin...i have my own custom form that i need to include a calender date-picker widget to it.

Comment: than the best way would be including jquery datepicker

Comment: ya thats what im doing, thanks.  YOu can include that as an answer and ill check it off.